# Element font-family must be declared

Tags: android

when i open a project from github ,the folder from res folder has a xml resource product_famliy.xml but android studio has a error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
E:\googledownload\PaperPlane-master\app\src\main\res\font\product_family.xml
Error:Error: Unsupported type 'font'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> E:\googledownload\PaperPlane-master\app\src\main\res\font\product_family.xml: Error: Unsupported type 'font'
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 21.311 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/product_sans_regular"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/product_sans_regular"/>

    <font
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/product_sans_italic"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/product_sans_italic"/>

</font-family>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you need Android Studio 3.0

Answer (score 0):

It is a new feature in new Android O version (android 26).
To get it working with fonts in XML you need to have installed Android Studio 3.x and compile with the newest verion (26).

In addition see here: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html

Comment: Which is pretty stupid considering they never mention that on the page...Then they mention somewhere else that its supposed to work with AS 2.4, then again whats the point of 2.4 if they dont even release that (last update was in April) but keep working on 3.0 (which is in beta). Can do Google anything right? Edit: Specifically meant this page: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html

Comment: I'm compiling with AS 3.0 beta 4, buildtools and compilesdk 26 and still can't make this work. I'm getting a "Unsupported type 'font'" error.

Comment: Are you using the newest version of support library's?

Comment: @ZShock & rebuild ?

Comment: @HannoGödecke I solved the problem by updating gradle to the corresponding 3.0.0-beta 4 version. Thanks anyway!